# 'bool' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to work on a Django app and I would like to check if the boolean object in the database is False and save it as True, but every time I get the error above, I would appreciate any assistance or insight on what I'm doing wrong.

views.py

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        for data in Mpesa.objects.all():

            all_receipts = data.MpesaReceiptNumber

            status = data.Completed

            verify_receipt = request.POST['verify'].upper()

            if verify_receipt in all_receipts:

                if status == False:
                    status = True
                    status.save()
                    return redirect('realtor:create')
```

models.py

```
class Mpesa(models.Model):
    MpesaReceiptNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
    Amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    TransactionDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    Completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views.py you set `status = data.Completed` which creates a variable called status with the boolean value that `data.Completed` holds. So that means that the status variable doesn't have the attribute save.

We need to set the `completed` field to `True` then save the data object.

Try this:

```
if status == False:
    data.completed = True
    data.save()
    return redirect('realtor:create')
```